# Create a web installer msi package which reads configuration file while install

Tags: deployment, windows-installer

I need to create a msi package which reads from a configuration file(settings) and installs the package.

Please help me how to to create a msi package which reads configuration file at the time of install.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes the configuration differences between each installation? Maybe you can use MSI properties like `ProductName, ProductCode, UpgradeCode, Manufacturer, ARPHELPLINK, ARPCOMMENTS, ARPCONTACT, ARPURLINFOABOUT, ARPURLUDATEINFO`

Comment: Ok, let me add more information. Basically I wanted to create a msi package which creates website by reading configuration file for website name, application pool name etc... while installing. Its a dynamic reading while installing. I know that we can do this, but not at all any pointers how to do. Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass custom parameters like this:

```
setup.msi /qb /l* log.txt WebSiteName=one PoolName=two
```

If you create your Setup package using Visual Studio then [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16767/How-to-Pass-Command-Line-Arguments-to-MSI-Installe) shows how to pass parameters to custom install actions.

[Visual Studio Setup - projects and custom actions](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/visual-studio-setup---projects-and-custom-actions/)

Comment: So, If I need to create a website while installing, do I need to add a custom action for this or are there any built in features I can use?

Comment: You need to add  custom actions to pass custom properties to your MSI files via command line. I added a link to an article on how to create.